# Skipping a Visual Studio 2013 smaller-version Update

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have VS 2013 Professional edition and its current version is Update 2. I'd like to upgrade my VS 2013 to Update 4.  My question: Do I need to install Update 3 before doing Update 4, or simply install Update 4 without needing Update 3?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is cumulative and so you can install Update 4 without the intermediate step of installing Update 3.